# Any way to find all incoming edges to a node in a directed graph?

Tags: matlab, graph

I'm trying to add up the weights of all the incoming edges to a `node("mynode")` in a directed graph (digraph). How do I do it efficiently?

One way is to use `findedge(s,mynode)` by trying all the nodes in place of s, and if it exists, add the weight.

But this is really inefficient if I have a sparse matrix. What else can I do? I was hoping for something like `findedge(:, mynode)`.

Answer (score 0):

Found it, use the predecessor() function to to find the predecessors. Now you dont have to check every node of the graph.